# Efficient way to delete AppServer with its all databases and forests using xquery

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

We are using MarkLogic v9.0.7 and we have multiple AppServers, Databases and Forests created for testing purpose.

For Example, 
let's say, AppServer Name is **testappserver**.

How can i delete **testappserver** AppServer along with its forests and databases using xquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use [`ml-gradle`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle), a tool that was built for deploying code & configuration to MarkLogic. It's well documented and based on the widely use `gradle` tool. MarkLogic University even has [a series of courses showing how to use ml-gradle](https://mlu.marklogic.com/ondemand/index.xqy?q=Series%3A%22ml-gradle%22). This approach is the repeatable way to address your question.

Deleting your app server and related databases and forests with XQuery calls would require several calls using the Admin API. Alternatively, sending a [DELETE to /v1/rest-apis[name]](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/DELETE/v1/rest-apis/[name]) should do the job.